# Doxygen's param[out], references and constructors

Tags: c++, doxygen

Please consider the following example:

```
class Example
{
    int &_m;

public:
    /**
     * An example constructor.
     *
     * @param myint Reference to some int.
     */
    Example(int& myint)
        : _m(myint)
    {
    }

    void change()
    {
        _m = 5;
    }
};
```

Should I mark the `myint` parameter `@param[out]`? The constructor itself doesn't use it as an output argument, it is however stored in the class and can be modified by the `change()` method.

Does the following rule of thumb make sense: `@param[in]` for `const` pointers and references, `@param[in,out]` for non-`const` ones?

Comment: Personally, I would say that it's best to avoid this kind of design where possible, where you're putting references into classes. Prefer a smart pointer, so that you can decide how ownership is dealt with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is for you and readers of your class, so it should provide the information that will make it most clear what's going on. The object seems to be designed to write to the reference. So marking it as an `out` parameter is not unreasonable. If it accurately communicates the intended use of the reference parameter, then you should use it as such.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the following rule of thumb make sense: @param[in] for const pointers and references, @param[in,out] for non-const ones?

Yes, but if you read and write to the reference object, then it is [in,out]. If you just write, then it is [out].